# How to remove "DEPRECATION: stub! is deprecated. Use stub instead." message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The question is a bit odd formulated but what I want is an alternative for `stub!` in Rspec which doesn't produce a deprecation warning.

**The scenario:**

I use `stub!` to stub certain helper methods in my helper spec.

For instance

```
stub!(:t_with_partner_lookup).and_return("test")
```

Rspec than suggests to use `stub` without the exclamation mark.

So I write (as suggested):

```
stub(:t_with_partner_lookup).and_return("test")
```

However this produces an error:

```
Stub :t_with_partner_lookup received unexpected message :and_return with ("test")
```

In another question that I found, I had to use the `helper.` prefix. I did, but it didn't remove the deprecation warning instead it produced an error.

```
helper.stub(:t_with_partner_lookup).and_return("test")
```

Produces:

```
undefined method `t_with_partner_lookup' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x00000103256d50>
```

I also tried this syntax but that produces the same error as noted above:

```
helper.stub(:t_with_partner_lookup){"test"}
```

What is the correct syntax for stubbing a helper method?

**Gems I use**:

- rails 3.2.17
- most recent version of rspec-rails

Ruby version 2.1.0

Comment: I am not sure whether this answers your query or not but see this http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/rspec-2-14-is-released#core_deprecation_output_now_configurable

Comment: This will only redirect the deprecation messages to a seperate log file. Could be a solution but it's ignoring the 'real' problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it, by using the allow syntax:

```
allow(self).to receive(:t_with_partner_lookup).and_return("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to try

```
helper = Object.new.extend SomeHelper
helper.stub(:t_with_partner_lookup).and_return('test')
```

Comment: Rspec now has the helper method built-in, making the first line irrelevant.