# RSpec: How to create a helper stub method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to stub a helper method from my helper:

```
# sessions_helper.rb
require 'rest_client'

module SessionsHelper
  BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1234"

  def current_user?(token)
    sessions_url = BASE_URL + "/sessions"
    headers = {"X-AuthToken" => 12345}

    begin
      RestClient.get(sessions_url, headers)
      return true
    rescue RestClient::BadRequest
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

I try to stub the current_user? to always return true in my unit test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsHelper do
  it "Should not get current user with random token" do
    SessionsHelper.stub(:current_user?).and_return(true)
    expect(current_user?(12345)).to eq(false)
  end
end
```

But the test still pass (I expect it returns true instead).

Is there something I miss to configure the stub method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the method on `SessionsHelper`. You are calling it on `self`. So try stubbing the method on self.

```
describe SessionsHelper do
  it "Should not get current user with random token" do
    stub(:current_user?).and_return(true)
    expect(current_user?(12345)).to eq(false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but now I got this error:Failure/Error: stub(:current_user?).and_return(true)
       Stub :current_user? received unexpected message :and_return with (true)

Answer (score 0):

`any_instance` should do what you want:

```
SessionsHelper.any_instance.stub(:current_user?).and_return(true)
```

As @Vimsha says, you got confused between the module and the instance, which is easy to do.

Comment: I got this error: undefined method `any_instance' for SessionsHelper:Module. I am using rails-rspec and rails 4.0

Comment: Hmm, you might try `allow` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373018/how-to-remove-deprecation-stub-is-deprecated-use-stub-instead-message).